# Azure EventHub Push/Pull?

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

When it comes to Apache Kafka, on the consumer side I know it's a pull model. What about Azure EventHubs? Are they pull or push?

From what I've gathered so far unlike kafka event hubs "push" events to the listeners. Can someone confirm? Any additional details or references would be helpful.

A simple google search landed me on the [this](https://www.serverless360.com/blog/what-is-azure-event-hub#:%7E:text=Transport%20Protocols%20(HTTPs%2FAMQP)&text=On%20the%20consuming%20side%2C%20since,AMQP%20is%20the%20only%20option.) page to back up my claim

Is there a simple way to test this theory out?

Comment: Azure Event Hub `pushes` events to a "event processor" client. The event processor can do `checkpoint` to denote upto which event in the event stream it has caught up with.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer to this is that the model for consuming events depends on the type of client that your application has chosen to use.  The official Azure SDK packages offer consumer types that are push-based and those that are pull-based.

You don't mention the specific language that you're using but, since you're comparing to Kafka, I'll assume that you're interested in Java.  The `azure-messaging-eventhubs` family of packages are the current generation of the Azure SDK and has the following clients for reading events:

- `EventProcessorClient`: This is a push-based client intended to serve as the primary consumer of events in production scenarios for the majority of workloads. It is responsible for reading and processing events for all partitions of an Event Hub and collaborates with other EventProcessorClient instances using the same Event Hub and consumer group to balance work between them. A high degree of fault tolerance is built-in, allowing the processor to be resilient in the face of errors.
- `EventHubConsumerAsyncClient`: This is a push-based client focused on reading events from a single partition using a Flux-based subscription via the Reactor library. This client requires applications to own responsibility for resilience and processing state persistence.
- `EventHubConsumerClient`: This is a pull-based client focused on reading events from a single partition using an iterator pattern. This client requires applications to own responsibility for resilience and processing state persistence.

More information around the package, its types, and basic usage in the [Azure Event Hubs client library for Java overview](https://learn.microsoft.com//java/api/overview/azure/messaging-eventhubs-readme?view=azure-java-stable).  More detailed samples can be found in the [samples overview](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/tree/main/sdk/eventhubs/azure-messaging-eventhubs/src/samples), including those for [Consuming events](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/main/sdk/eventhubs/azure-messaging-eventhubs/src/samples/java/com/azure/messaging/eventhubs/ConsumeEvents.java) and [Using the EventProcessorClient](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/main/sdk/eventhubs/azure-messaging-eventhubs/src/samples/java/com/azure/messaging/eventhubs/EventProcessorClientSample.java).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Azure Event Hub **push** events to event consumers, there is *no* need to 'poll' for consuming the events. The event processor defines `event handlers` which are invoked as new events are ingested into the event stream.
The event consumer can do something called as `checkpoint` that marks the event upto which the events have been consumed.
See the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-features#event-consumers) for more details.

Comment: This is not fully correct; Event Hubs communicates via the AMQP protocol, where consumers are responsible for placing credits on the link to signal the intent to receive data.   Azure SDK packages offer both push and pull-based clients.  Your details are specific to the event processor type, which is one of those available.